# error using slick.js in angular 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, slick.js

I am trying to use slick.js a carousel framework in angular.

I tried `npm install slick --save' and adding the downloaded files in my scripts and styles json objects.

that didn't work so then I imported the css and js in my angular index.html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

then I install jquery typings by doing

`npm install typings/jquery --save-dev`

then in the relevant ts file I use slick and import jquery

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
...

ngOnInit(){
jQuery<any>('cuisinecarousel').slick({
      centerMode: true,
      centerPadding: '60px',
      slidesToShow: 3,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 768,
          settings: {
            arrows: false,
            centerMode: true,
            centerPadding: '40px',
            slidesToShow: 3
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          settings: {
            arrows: false,
            centerMode: true,
            centerPadding: '40px',
            slidesToShow: 1
          }
        }
      ]

    });
...
}
```

but then I get this error:

```
ERROR in mainroot/venuepage/venuepage.component.ts(451,36): error TS2551: Property 'slick' does not exist on type 'JQuery<any>'. Did you mean 'click'?
```

anyone have similar issues and how to fix?

Gratzi

I found this: Going to try it and see if it fixes

https://github.com/devmark/ngx-slick

Answer (score 3):

try using:

```
declare var $: any;
```

instead of:

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
```